# How to call fnRender dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

My requirement is based on the user defined column array, I have to create aoColumns. But fnRender is not working as expected, like I'm trying to display icon+text.

```
var userDefinedColumn = ["position"];

var dataTable = null;

var columnMap = {
    "name": {
        "mDataProp": "name",
        "title": "Name",
        "bSortable": false,
        "bVisible": true,
        "fnRender": function (oObj, val) {
            return "<span>" + val + "</span>";
        }
    },
    "position": {
        "mDataProp": "position",
        "title": "Position",
        "bVisible": true,
        "bSortable": false,
        "fnRender": function (oObj, val) {
            return "<i class='add' rid='" + oObj.aData.name + "'></i><span>" + val + "</span>";
        }
    }
}

    function fnGetTableColumn() {
        var aoColumn = [];
        for (var index = 0; index < userDefinedColumn.length; index++) {
            var obj = userDefinedColumn[index];
            aoColumn.push(columnMap[obj]);
        }
        fnRenderTable(aoColumn);
    }

    function fnRenderTable(aoColumn) {
        dataTable = $("#table-example").dataTable({
            "bProcessing": false,
            "bServerSide": false,
            "sAjaxSource": 'sample1.json',
            "sAjaxDataProp": "data",
            "aoColumns": aoColumn
        });
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    fnGetTableColumn();
});
```

The issue in above code is fnrender function is not working as expected.

Expected Result:

```
<td><i class="add" rid="1"></i><span>Developer</span></td>
```

Actual Result :

```
<td>Developer</td>
```

Comment: Just to be sure what version of datatables are you using?

Comment: According to the datatables docs, http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns, fnRender is deprecated. It's replaced by "mRender".